# How do I make the Line of code to the next line when running program?

Tags: python, whitespace

I have the right code I think but it  says on the test case that my whitespace differs.
[image of test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kHLZj.png). I'm a beginner sorry if this is a dumb question.

```
services={'oil change':35,'tire rotation':19,'car wash':7}  
service_list = input('Enter desired auto service:\n')   
print('You entered:',service_list)  
payment = int(input('How much are you paying?'))
```

Comment: Please do not vandalize or deface your question.  By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put `\n` in the string on line 4, just like on line 2. Otherwise, that necessary newline will be missing.

```py
services={'oil change':35,'tire rotation':19,'car wash':7}  
service_list = input('Enter desired auto service:\n')   
print('You entered:',service_list)  
payment = int(input('How much are you paying?\n'))
```